# New (?) leads on the "I'm not interested by frameworks" problem

Tags: discussion

Like [this poor man](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/im-embarrassed-that-im-not-answering-questions), I'm suffering of not being able to find question I am able to answer. Unlike him, this comes from the fact that I don't have as many years of experience he had. But I still have some experience, and I should be able to use it. So I wondered why I wasn't able to find the question I could answer and one of the reason was the following:

**The big majority of the question involving either AJAX or simply javascript uses jquery or another framework...** (I have a similar problem with PHP too, but not so extreme)

So naturally, I could ask why jquery is so great, and convert myself, but that wouldn't help find the question I would be able to answer now. I have reasons not to use framework, both private and professional, so let's not divert from the problem I and others are trying to solve: [What would be the best and most way to find framework-free question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36695/how-can-i-see-questions-about-java-no-i-mean-really-about-java)

One thing that helps a lot is [the recent integration of the interesting tab](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). In combinination with the interesting and ignored tags, it gives me a better choice of questions to answer, but I still can't know all the frameworks and anyway won't be able to insert all the frameworks tag as shown on the first edit of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36695/how-can-i-see-questions-about-java-no-i-mean-really-about-java). So what would be possible solution?

Removing the language tag from framework question wouldn't be a good idea, as [it wouldn't please some people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38413/is-it-fine-to-tag-retag-questions-on-specific-frameworks-with-a-language-tag).

A "pure" tag, such as [the proposed justjava](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36695/how-can-i-see-questions-about-java-no-i-mean-really-about-java), could be an option. However it would need some kind of massive re-tagging. I don't think it could be worth it.

One could try the [one tag to rule them all approach](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34547/auto-assign-language-tags-to-questions-based-on-other-tags), and auto-assign all possible frameworks under the frameworks tag, but as it was pointed that would be a [maintenance nightmare](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34547/auto-assign-language-tags-to-questions-based-on-other-tags/34548#34548). Only the really motivated would be able to do such an herculean task. Like maybe the user who need such a thing. Maybe there could be an option for the user to create and use their own macro-tag to assemble many tags under one, and put them on the filters. Or maybe SO would automatically maintain the frameworks macro-tag in the sense that it would recognize if a question is about frameworks (simply because the word appear in the question) and then would suggest that one of the tag would be designated as framework...

To tell the truth, I'm not sure if any of those options could be remotely viable. But I would rather speak up than not saying anything and letting something that could be potentially beneficial to the community go to waste.

So what are you thoughts on the subject?

Comment: I'd repeat this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69206/anybody-annoyed-by-tags-that-bring-up-a-lot-of-unrelated-questions/69269#69269

Answer (score 2):

Given the essential nature of horses and water, I don't think you'll get any help by adding a tag. No one will use it. You could go through all the questions tagged with the existing tags and try to add it, but now you're back where you started.

Answering questions on SO is a bit like being a baleen whale; you have to pump tons of seawater through the filter to get enough krill.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any objection to what you're asking for, but I think you're putting the cart before the horse. You're assuming that there are a reasonable number of SO users who want to *ask* framework-free javascript questions, when all you know for sure is that there is at least one user who wants to *answer* these questions.

I can't say that these users don't exist, but I'm not aware of anyone clamoring for a change to help them *ask* in the manner you're describing.

I certainly understand that there could be reasons why you're unable to use jquery to solve a problem, but the reality is that in most cases this prohibition does not exist. In other words, the demand for javascript gurus who don't know jquery is very low.

Comment: Maybe I made my case too specific, as I wanted to discuss the general case or maybe is javascript the one language where one can witness such an environment and in this case I got unlucky. Also I don't wanted to imply that it was a situation would be encountered often, as I wanted to know the relevance of what I was asking. If it was relevant enough, maybe then I would have asked for a feature request.

Comment: "would have asked" in the last sentence should be "will ask". A shame I can't edit my comment...